How to combine two variables (timepoint and treatment) using "factor" and "paste" but only timepoint within treatment?
I have a data frame with 3 timepoints and 5 treatment, I want to create a new variable to combine timepoints within each treatment for a post-hoc multiple mean comparison.
Time_w_Trt <- factor(with(df,
                          paste(treatment, timepoint, sep = "_")))

However the above script takes into account all possible combinations between treatments and timepoints, I only want to combine all timepoints within each treatment. Can anyone suggest the best way to modify the above script?
Many thanks!

Without a reprex it is somewhat difficult to help! For tips on writing a reprex see this link. My guess is that your data looks something like this?
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)

examp_data = tibble::tribble(~time, ~treat, ~val,
                     1, "A", 1,
                     2, "A", 2,
                     3, "A", 3,
                     1, "B", 2,
                     2, "B", NA,
                     3, "B", NA,
                     1, "C", 3, 
                     2, "C", NA,
                     3, "C", 1)

You can simply make the dataset wide using pivot_wider or dcast like this
examp_data |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = c(time,treat), values_from = val,
              names_glue = "{treat}_{time}")
#> # A tibble: 1 × 9
#>     A_1   A_2   A_3   B_1   B_2   B_3   C_1   C_2   C_3
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     2     3     2    NA    NA     3    NA     1

## or if you are want to use data.table 

dt = setDT(examp_data) 


dcast(dt, . ~ treat + time ,  value.var = "val") 
#> Key: <.>
#>         .   A_1   A_2   A_3   B_1   B_2   B_3   C_1   C_2   C_3
#>    <char> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num>
#> 1:      .     1     2     3     2    NA    NA     3    NA     1

Created on 2024-05-14 with reprex v2.1.0
